# open a tmux window with x panes to run tasks in parallel, from bash

Tags: bash, tmux

I have a script that pushes multiple builds at the same time, using the parallel command.

Typically, either everything works, or nothing does, but it's not a very robust way to do it.

the script is like:

```
parallel ::: 'docker push a' 'docker push b' 'docker push c'
```

Is there a way, using bash where I could make an array of the commands, like

```
commands = (docker push a' 'docker push b' 'docker push c')
```

and then open a tmux window with a pane per task and run each task in its own pane? so I would see all the outputs separately.

In practice, I'm on MacOS using zsh, but a bash compliant solution would be more portable.

Comment: `parallel --tmux docker push ::: a b c` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
for i in a b c; do
    if [ -z "$W" ]; then
        W=$(tmux neww -P "docker push $i")
    else
        tmux splitw -t$W "docker push $i" \; selectl tiled
    fi
done
```

You may want to set the `remain-on-exit` option on the window if you don't want the panes to close until you have read the output.

There is also stuff like https://github.com/greymd/tmux-xpanes although I have not used it.

Comment: I went for tmux-xpanes because it does exactly what I need. Thanks for the answer though.